# How to paste text into input fields that block it?

Tags: google-chrome, copy-paste

On many webpages they are blocking copy/paste using JavaScript.

Is there any way for making such inputs work as the should (e.g. enable copy/paste)?

I’m using Google Chrome.

Comment: Its very unlikely. They don't put in that for no reason, so they'll also block any kind of way to circumvent it.

Comment: There are lots of way of circumventing such scripts and a dedicated browser extension should solve many wariants of this issue.

Comment: If you already know this, why do you post the question?

Comment: I know it is doable, I don't know about any such extension.

Comment: If you were using Firefox, you could go to about:config and change dom.event.clipboardevents.enabled to false. I don't know if something similar exists in Chrome.

Comment: If you use Linux you have a 2nd copy/paste buffer set, controlled by whatever the mouse has highlighted and middle button clickign to paste

Comment: If I had more points on this site, I'd put a bounty on this. I seriously hate sites that do that...

Answer (score 83):

Simply highlight the text and drag it into the text field. Try it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/k0eqs52c/)!

This works for me in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Great solution!  In chrome you can put this string into the address bar "data:text/html, <html contenteditable>"  (without the quotes) to get a blank canvas. I created a bookmark to that.  Now I can paste my text into this blank page, then drag it into the fields that need filling.

Comment: This is the best. Trying to run js in the developer console was giving me a headache. Many thanks!

Comment: Cool, man? thank you.. You saved my time.

Comment: This doesn't work when the &*@(!$ web developers disable `ondrag` too. 

Comment: Awesome, in my case it was an application acting as a browser wrapper. I couldn't do a drag & drop of the string from a notepad file, but it worked from a wordpad file!

Comment: This didn't work for me.

Answer (score 42):

Press F12 and paste the following code into the console.

```
var allowPaste = function(e){
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  return true;
};
document.addEventListener('paste', allowPaste, true);
```

Comment: This didn't work for me with Chrome Version 101.0.4951.64 (Official Build) (64-bit) to try to paste into the password field of Super Auto Pets.

Answer (score 19):

If you're using Firefox, I found the following solution. Not sure what minimum version is required, however.

1. Go to `about:config`
2. Search for `dom.event.clipboardevents.enabled`
3. Double-click it to change the value to `false`

This allowed me to paste immediately after changing it. I didn't even have to restart the browser.

Answer (score 12):

Here's an open source Chrome Extention

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dont-fuck-with-paste/nkgllhigpcljnhoakjkgaieabnkmgdkb

If you're interested in the code https://github.com/jswanner/DontFuckWithPaste

Comment: This should be the correct answer. Don't Fuck With Paste has 465 stars on Github and practically a 5 star rating on the Chrome Store - with 413 reviews. This really helped me. Thanks!

Comment: For me, this extension helps, but does not work on all sites.

Answer (score 10):

It's hacky and won't work always but a lot of the time there is just a listener set for <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> / <kbd>CTRL+V</kbd> and you can get around it by using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>INS</kbd> / <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>INS</kbd> instead of copy / paste.

If they are doing something goofy like using flash to write an empty string to the clipboard in a loop (twitch) then you are out of luck.

Answer (score 4):

Decide to add my solution to this (making a bookmarklet inspired from this repo and extension https://github.com/jswanner/DontFuckWithPaste) This bookmarklet will also allow copying on documents that disable that using javascript.

```
javascript:(function(){
  allowCopyAndPaste = function(e){ 
      e.stopImmediatePropagation(); 
      return true;
  };
  document.addEventListener('copy', allowCopyAndPaste, true);
  document.addEventListener('paste', allowCopyAndPaste, true);
  document.addEventListener('onpaste', allowCopyAndPaste, true);
})();
```

[AllowCopyAndPaste](http://javascript:(function()%7BallowCopyAndPaste%20=%20function(e)%7B%20e.stopImmediatePropagation();%20return%20true;%7D;document.addEventListener('copy',%20allowCopyAndPaste,%20true);document.addEventListener('paste',%20allowCopyAndPaste,%20true);document.addEventListener('onpaste',%20allowCopyAndPaste,%20true);%7D)();)

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest workaround (in terms of user-friendliness) for Google Chrome would be adding [Allow Copy](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-copy/abidndjnodakeaicodfpgcnlkpppapah) extension.

Comment: Carefully vet that extension before installing. Reviewers are claiming it's malware.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply disable JavaScript on the page  using a simple bookmarklet. From. http://javascript.about.com/library/bldis.htm

If you create a bookmark that contains the following script as the link (or even paste this code into the address bar and press enter) then it will rip all the JavaScript off of the current page:

```
javascript:void(d=document);if(frames.length){alert('Script%20doesn/'t%20work%20in%20frames');}else{while((el=d.getElementsByTagName('script')).length){el[0].parentNode.removeChild(el[0]);};onerror=function(){};d.close();}
```

The problem of course is that while you will now be able to paste into that text box if the form used JavaScript to submit the form then that too will be broken.

Answer (score 0):

On windows you can use [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/)

syntax:

```
::whatever::
Send [....text… Use  {enter} for line breaks]
return
```

example: if you type `xyz` it will write the text below (as if it was written)

```
::xyz::
Send hi {enter} This a new line  {enter}. Another new line  {enter} whatsoever. {enter} 
return
```

Comment: I like this one: 
^Q::
SendInput, {Raw}%clipboard%

CTRL-Q sends the contents of the keyboard as input (similar to typing it in)

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, I maintain an open-source app [DevComrade](https://github.com/postprintum/devcomrade) which, amongst other things, simulates typing of the current clipboard text upon hitting <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Ins</kbd>. Perfect for those pesky websites and desktop apps messing with the paste functionality.

Answer (score 0):

On Microsoft Windows, I use a voice command in [Dragon NaturallySpeaking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_NaturallySpeaking) to paste text from the clipboard into input fields that block it copy-pasting:

```
Sub Main
    SendKeys Clipboard
    Rem originalClipboard = Clipboard
    Rem Clipboard("str(" & originalClipboard & ")")
    Rem SendKeys "originalClipboard"
    Rem Wait(1)
    Rem Clipboard(originalClipboard)
End Sub
```

[image]

I've used that solution for many years with Dragon NaturallySpeaking 12.5 + Windows 7 + mostly Chrome, it works on all websites. The only limitation is if the copied text is very long, in which case one gets the following error message:

[image]

I've never bothered improving the script to accept a very long text input, since fields expecting a long input text pretty much always accept copy-pasting, but that should be straightforward if needs be.

Answer (score 0):

There have been multiple solutions for Windows listed here. This one is for `Linux` desktops. The approach is the same - *emulate keystrokes for the clipboard contents*.

Create a shell script with the following lines and bind it to a key sequence (e.g. <kbd>Strl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>):

```
#!/bin/sh    
clip_text="$(xclip -o -sel clipboard)"
sleep 0.5
xdotool type --clearmodifiers --delay 200 "$clip_text"
```

Both `xclip` and `xdotool` are present in any Linux distribution repository.